# Discord.js SQLITE_ERROR: no such column: stats.guild_id

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot and I have run into a run problem with database.

I have two databases: one is for keeping stats(works fine), other is configs. Whenever I run needed command and try to read data from the configs database it for some reason tries to read from the stats one. I have looked through the code and I can't seem to find the problem. When command is run, I get this in log:

> SQLITE_ERROR: no such column: stats.guild_id

Here are the two files. One is for the main bot script other is command script that is run.

Main script:

```
const bot = new Discord.Client({disableEveryone: true});
const fs = require("fs");
const localconfig = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./local-config.json", "utf8"));
const wordbanks = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./modules/wordbanks.json", "utf8"));
const antilang = require("./modules/anti-lang.js");
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

const seqStats = new Sequelize('database', 'user', 'password', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    logging: false,
    storage: './db/stats.sqlite',
});

const seqConfig = new Sequelize('database', 'user', 'password', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    logging: false,
    storage: './db/configs.sqlite',
});

const Stats = seqStats.define('stats', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        unique: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    },
    username: Sequelize.STRING,
    xp_bal: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        defaultValue: 0,
        allowNull: false,
    },
  money_bal: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    defaultValue: 0,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  warn_bal: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    defaultValue: 0,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  mute_bal: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    defaultValue: 0,
    allowNull: false,
  },
    kick_bal: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        defaultValue: 0,
        allowNull: false,
    },
  ban_bal: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    defaultValue: 0,
    allowNull: false,
    },
    }, {
        timestamps: false,
});

const Configs = seqConfig.define('configs', {
    server_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        unique: true,
        primaryKey: true,
    },
    guild_id: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        unique: true,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    prefix: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        defaultValue: "$",
        allowNull: false,
    },
    configs_active: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        defaultValue: "NO",
        allowNull: false,
    },
    stats_active :{
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        defaultValue: "NO",
        allowNull: false,
    },
    defaultRole: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        defaultValue: "NONE",
        allowNull: false,
    },
    modLogsChannel: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        defaultValue: "NONE",
        allowNull: false,
    },
    economyLogsChannel: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        defaultValue: "NONE",
        allowNull: false,
    },
    welcomeChannel: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        defaultValue: "NONE",
        allowNull: false,
    },
    chatLogsChannel: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        defaultValue: "NONE",
        allowNull: false,
    },
    todoChannel: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        defaultValue: "NONE",
        allowNull: false,
    },
    suggestionsChannel: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        defaultValue: "NONE",
        allowNull: false,
    },
    bugReportsChannel: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        defaultValue: "NONE",
        allowNull: false,
        },
    }, {
    timestamps: false,
});

bot.on("ready", async () => {
    antilang(bot);
    Stats.sync();
        Configs.sync();
    console.log(`${bot.user.username} is online!`);
});

//==============Command Files Section================
bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();
bot.aka = new Discord.Collection();

fs.readdir("./commands", (err, files) => {

    if (err) console.log(err)

    let jsfile = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() === "js")
    if (jsfile.length <= 0) {
        return console.log("[LOGS] Couldn't Find Commands!");
    }

    jsfile.forEach((f, i) => {
        let pull = require(`./commands/${f}`);
        bot.commands.set(pull.config.name, pull);
        pull.config.aka.forEach(aka => {
            bot.aka.set(aka, pull.config.name)
        });
    });
});

//==============Bot Joins Guild Section================
bot.on("guildCreate", async (guild) => {
    console.log("Joined new guild: " + guild.name + " with ID: " + guild.id + ".");

        const configs = await Configs.findOne({where: { server_id: guild.id } });

        if (!configs){
            Configs.create({
                    server_id: guild.id,
                    guild_id: `${guild.id}`,
            });
            console.log(`No records found for ${guild.name}(${guild.id}). Created new entry.`);
        }
});

//==============Bot Leaves Guild Section================
bot.on("guildDelete", async (guild) => {
    console.log("Left guild: " + guild.name + " with ID: " + guild.id + ".");
});

//==============Member Joins Guild Section================
bot.on("guildMemberAdd", async (member) => {
    console.log(`New member ${member.user.username} has joined guild ${member.guild.name}.`);
    const configs = await Configs.findOne({where: { server_id: member.guild.id } });
    const configs_active = configs.get("configs_active");
    if(configs_active == "YES"){
        const defaultRole = configs.get("defaultRole");
        let defRole = member.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === defaultRole);
        member.roles.add(defRole);

        const guild_id = configs.get("guild_id");
        const welcomeChannel = configs.get("welcomeChannel");
        if(welcomeChannel == "NONE"){
            return;
        } else {
            bot.guilds.resolve(guild_id).channels.resolve(welcomeChannel).send(`A member has joined: ${member.user.username} :partying_face:`);
        }
    }
        const stats = await Stats.findOne({ where: { id: member.id } });
        if (!stats) {
                Stats.create({
                        id: member.id,
                        username: member.user.username,
                });
                console.log(`No records found for ${member.user.username}(${member.user.id}). Created new entry.`);
            }
});

//==============Member Leaves Guild Section================
bot.on("guildMemberRemove", async (member) => {
    if(member.id != bot.user.id){
        console.log("Member " + member.user.username + " has left the guild.");
        const configs = await Configs.findOne({where: { server_id: member.guild.id } });
        const configs_active = configs.get("configs_active");
        if(configs_active == "YES"){
            const guild_id = configs.get("guild_id");
            const welcomeChannel = configs.get("welcomeChannel");
            if(welcomeChannel == "NONE"){
                return;
            } else {
                bot.guilds.resolve(localconfig.logsguild).channels.resolve(localconfig.welcomeChannel).send(`A member has left: ${member.user.username} :disappointed_relieved:`);
            }
        }
    } else {
        return;
    }
});

//==============onMessage Section================
bot.on("message", async message => {

    if(message.author.bot){
      return;
    } else if (message.channel.type === "dm") {
        return message.channel.send("Please only speak to me in servers that I'm in.\nI'm not made to be your personal servant!");
    } else if (message.mentions.has(bot.user)){
          let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * wordbanks.tagreplies.length);
          message.channel.send(wordbanks.tagreplies[index]);
    }

  let xpAmount = Math.floor(Math.random() * (15 - 1) + 1);
  let moneyAmount = Math.floor(Math.random() * (15 - 1) + 1);

  const stats = await Stats.findOne({ where: { id: message.author.id } });
  if (!stats) {
            console.log(`Can't find any database records for ${message.author.username}(${message.author.id}).`)
  } else {
        const money_bal = stats.get("money_bal");
        const xp_bal = stats.get("xp_bal");
            if(xp_bal == "Infinity"){
                    console.log(`${message.author.username} has infinite xp.`);
                    const editMoney = await Stats.update({ money_bal: money_bal + moneyAmount }, { where: { id: message.author.id } });
            } else if(money_bal == "Infinity"){
                    console.log(`${message.author.username} has infinite money.`);
                    const editXP = await Stats.update({ xp_bal: xp_bal + xpAmount }, { where: { id: message.author.id } });
            } else if(money_bal == "Infinity" && xp_bal == "Infinity"){
                console.log(`${message.author.username} has infinite money & xp.`);
            } else {
                const editMoney = await Stats.update({ money_bal: money_bal + moneyAmount }, { where: { id: message.author.id } });
                const editXP = await Stats.update({ xp_bal: xp_bal + xpAmount }, { where: { id: message.author.id } });
            }
  }

    bot.emit('checkLang', message, Stats, Configs);
//==============Command Call Section================
    let prefix = localconfig.prefix;

    if (message.author.bot || message.channel.type === "dm") return;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(' ');
    let cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    let commandfile = bot.commands.get(cmd.slice(0)) || bot.commands.get(bot.aka.get(cmd.slice(0)))
    if (commandfile) commandfile.run(bot, message, args, Stats, Configs)
});

bot.login(localconfig.logintoken);
```

Command Script:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args, Configs) => {
  const configs = await Configs.findOne({where: { guild_id: message.guild.id } });
  const configs_active = configs.get("configs_active");
  const stats_active = configs.get("stats_active");
  const prefix = configs.get("prefix");
  const defRole = configs.get("defaultRole");
  const modLogsChannel = configs.get("modLogsChannel");
  const economyLogsChannel = configs.get("economyLogsChannel");
  const welcomeChannel = configs.get("welcomeChannel");
  const chatLogsChannel = configs.get("chatLogsChannel");
  const todoChannel = configs.get("todoChannel");
  const suggestionsChannel = configs.get("suggestionsChannel");
  const bugReportsChannel = configs.get("bugReportsChannel");

  let testEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle("BOT TEST")
  .setDescription("Config Test For Bot")
  .addField("Configs Active:", configs_active)
  .addField("Stats Active:", stats_active)
  .addField("Prefix:", prefix)
  .addField("Default Role:", defRole)
  .addField("ModLogs ID:", modLogsChannel)
  .addField("Economy ID:", economyLogsChannel)
  .addField("Welcome ID:", welcomeChannel)
  .addField("ChatLogs ID", chatLogsChannel)
  .addField("TODO ID:", todoChannel)
  .addField("Suggestions ID:", suggestionsChannel)
  .addField("Bug Reports ID:", bugReportsChannel)

  message.channel.send({embed: testEmbed});
}

module.exports.config = {
         name: "test",
         aka: ["testing"],
         usage: "$test",
         description: "Test",
         accessableby: "Anyone"
 }
```

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Why not just use 2 tables in 1 database?